# Ctrl space get eat by windows instead of passing to cygwin emacs

Tags: emacs, cygwin

I bind C-space to start selection 
but this is also the windows input method hotkey, so when never I press this under cygwin, it will eaten by the OS, is there any way to avoid this? how to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle you can tell Windows to let Emacs use that key when you are in Emacs.

For example, if you are on Windows XP then you can use `w32-register-hot-key` to let Emacs get that key, this way:

```
(w32-register-hot-key (kbd "C-SPC"))
```

But it is apparently the case that on Windows 7 (dunno about Vista or 8, but I'm guessing they too have the problem) `w32-register-hot-key` no longer has any effect.  In this case I think you are out of luck --- you will need to change the hotkey that Windows uses for the input method.